# create directive for join in uwp

Tags: win-universal-app

I have this query in my UWP project (I use EF7 and Sqlite in my app):

```
var query = (from s in db.tblStudent
         join h in db.tblTests on
         s.NameTest equals h.NameTest
         select( s.NameTest)).ToList();
```

When I compile my project with .net native I got this exception:

> 'System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' is missing metadata.

I studied http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html and 
[http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/method.html](http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html) links but I can not create a correct directive for `default.rd.xml`. 
Can anybody help me to write the correct directive?

Comment: Have you seen http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html?

Comment: yes,I already Have read it but my problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, these problems have been solved in the Updated version of Visual Studio 2015.